# Echoing record from specific table while using JOIN in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have tried googling but couldn't get any information to echo a record from specific table while I generate the query using JOIN.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

I want to get the `id` from `tbl1`. When I used,

```
echo $row->id
```

It does echo the `id` column from `tbl2`. What should I do to get the record from the table which I want? Thanks!

Comment: In a query, if the fields name are the same, the second override first. To avoid this, use `SELECT tbl1.*,tbl2.*`. But in your query the join condition is `tbl1.id = tbl2.id`, so where is the problem?

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't get the record from the field `tbl1` which has different record from `tbl2`. But it's solved now. I just need to make alias for table I want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use alias because in both tables you have same column name id, so you can use like that:

```
SELECT tbl1.id as id1,tbl2.id as id2 
FROM tbl1 
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

And:

```
echo $row->id1 // for table 1
echo $row->id2 // for table 2
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for saving my time.

Comment: @AlvianCasablancas: glad to help u friend. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because 2 table `tbl1` and `tbl2` both have same column named `id` and MySQL don't separate them and return `id` field of last table. So you need add alias name for `id` field.

`SELECT *, tbl1.id as id_tbl1 FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id`

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works as same as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT tbl1.id as tb1id,tbl2.id as tbl2id FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.id = tbl2.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works just like the others.